# How can we know the content of a file from a Javascript File object?

Tags: javascript, form-data

One common way to make asynchronous file upload that I could find on the web works as follow :

```
myUpload(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', this.uploadInput.files[0]);

  /* Do the upload with something like axios */ 
  axios.post('http://localhost:8000/upload', data)
    . ...
}
```

I cannot explain the following :

- the object `this.uploadInput.files[0]` is a `File` javascript object.
- From the documentation I could find (see for instance [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)), and from the log I tried on the console, javascript File objects store neither the file content, nor the file path.

Therefore, how can the FormData object retrieve the file data we want to send ?

Comment: JavaScript is not a stand-alone programming language in this context: it is there to [*script a host environment*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39946046/3757232), in this case the browser. It can manipulate the host using hooks that host provides. While the *browser* has full access, *JavaScript's* access is heavily mediated. In other words, it's browser voodoo and you just ask it to do it's thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormData` probably doesn't, but the browser does because when axios provides the `FormData` object to the browser's ajax features ([XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch)), the browser can use the data in¹ the `File` object to read and send the file.

Your own JavaScript code could also use the data in the `File` object to read the file, using [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (another browser-supplied feature).

`File` doesn't directly contain the file's data, but it does contain information the browser can use to read the file (without exposing its actual location to your code).

---

¹ Probably not literally *in* the `File` object. More likely an indirect relationship between the two using data privately-held by the browser.

Comment: I see. So it means for instance that if I use axios to post an object that contains my FormData as an attribute, then it would probably won't load the file data, because the browser will not detect it and 'work its magic'  ?

Comment: @Archimondain - I'd have to defer to the axios documentation on that, it depends on exactly what you're doing and whether axios supports it and ensures it provides the `FormData` object to the browser.

Comment: Well, I will test that. Thanks anyway.